# Add new element in for-loop with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, for-loop

In this table I would like to add a new table cell with jQuery.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="table">
  <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
    <td class="dataTableHeadingContent"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS; ?></td>
    <td class="dataTableHeadingContent"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS_MODEL; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($order->products); $i < $n; $i ++) {
    echo '<tr class="dataTableRow">';
    echo '  <td class="dataTableContent txta-r">' . $order->products[$i]['qty'] . '&nbsp;x&nbsp;' . $order->products[$i]['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '  <td class="dataTableContent txta-r">' . $order->products[$i]['model'] . '</td>';
    /* here should the new table cell be */
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  ?>
</table>
<?php include changes.php; ?>
```

The file changes.php is necessary in this CMS to change code without changing the original code.
The new tableheading isn't a problem.

```
$new_th = '<td class="dataTableHeadingContent">' . TABLE_NEW_CELL . '</td>';
?>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:contains('<?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS_MODEL; ?>')" ).after('<?php echo $new_th; ?>');
  });
</script>
```

But how can I add a new table cell in this for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td id='". $i ."' class="dataTableContent txta-r"> </td>"
```

this will add an empty cell with id starts from 0 to array size.

then in the jquery you can add the data to this cell by making a for loop from 0 to the same array size.